# troubles with overwriting sass variables

Tags: javascript, css, sass, compass-sass, lightgallery

I'm working with [lightGallery.js](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js) and I have some troubles with overwriting the [sass variables](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/docs/api.html#sass). The only variable I have been able to successfully overwrite is `$backdrop-opacity` all the other variables in `lg-variables.scss` does not take effect.

`/static` tree structure

```
├── config.rb
├── fonts
│   ├── lg.eot
│   ├── lg.svg
│   ├── lg.ttf
│   ├── lg.woff
│   ├── app-font.eot
│   ├── app-font.woff
│   └── app-font.woff2
├── images
│   └── logo.svg
├── javascripts
│   ├── components
│   │   └── lightgallery
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   ├── lg-fb-comment-box.css
│   │       │   ├── lg-fb-comment-box.css.map
│   │       │   ├── lg-fb-comment-box.min.css
│   │       │   ├── lg-transitions.css
│   │       │   ├── lg-transitions.css.map
│   │       │   ├── lg-transitions.min.css
│   │       │   ├── lightgallery.css
│   │       │   ├── lightgallery.css.map
│   │       │   └── lightgallery.min.css
│   │       ├── fonts
│   │       │   ├── lg.eot
│   │       │   ├── lg.svg
│   │       │   ├── lg.ttf
│   │       │   └── lg.woff
│   │       ├── img
│   │       │   ├── loading.gif
│   │       │   ├── video-play.png
│   │       │   ├── vimeo-play.png
│   │       │   └── youtube-play.png
│   │       ├── js
│   │       │   ├── lightgallery.js
│   │       │   ├── lightgallery.min.js
│   │       │   └── plugins
│   │       │       ├── lg-autoplay.min.js
│   │       │       ├── lg-fullscreen.min.js
│   │       │       └── lg-video.min.js
│   │       └── sass
│   │           ├── lg-animations.scss
│   │           ├── lg-autoplay.scss
│   │           ├── lg-fb-comment-box.scss
│   │           ├── lg-fonts.scss
│   │           ├── lg-fullscreen.scss
│   │           ├── lg-mixins.scss
│   │           ├── lg-pager.scss
│   │           ├── lg-share.scss
│   │           ├── lg-theme-default.scss
│   │           ├── lg-thumbnail.scss
│   │           ├── lg-transitions.scss
│   │           ├── lg-variables.scss
│   │           ├── lg-video.scss
│   │           ├── lg-zoom.scss
│   │           ├── lightgallery.scss
│   │           └── prepros.cfg
│   └── app.js
├── sass
│   ├── _base.scss
│   ├── app.scss
│   ├── _fonts.scss
│   └── lightgallery.scss
└── stylesheets
    ├── app.css
    └── lightgallery.css
```

`/sass/lightgallery.scss` file

```
@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lg-variables";
@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lg-mixins";
@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lg-fonts";
@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lg-theme-default";
@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lg-video";
@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lg-autoplay";
@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lg-fullscreen";

$backdrop-opacity: .02;

@import "../javascripts/components/lightgallery/sass/lightgallery";
```

Regardless of what variable I add after `$backdrop-opacity` like `$lg-toolbar-bg: rgba(12, 255, 0, 0.45);` doesn't change its value from the default `$lg-toolbar-bg: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) !default;`

Am I making a mistake in the `@import` order? I kind of clueless.

I order to make this post short here are the links to [`src/sass/lightgallery.scss`](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/blob/master/src/sass/lightgallery.scss) and [`src/sass/lg-variables.scss`](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/blob/master/src/sass/lg-variables.scss) on github

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$backdrop-opacity` isn't declared again in https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightgallery.js/blob/master/src/sass/lightgallery.scss You set it once, it's used once.